# Jenkins plugin “Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management”：click upload with no response

Tags: jenkins, plugins, upload

Recreate steps:

1. After installing the plug-in, click Jenkins HOME -> Manage Jenkins -> keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management;
2. Select the login.keychain file，and click "upload" button;
3. But the key chain file cannot be uploaded. Click upload and there is no response.

Error snapshot

[image: 1]

My enviroment:

- centos version:CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
- docker version: 20.10.22
- Jenkins version:2.375.2
- plugin version:105.v767485951b_d2

Answer (score 0):

Not that this helps massively, but I'm also suffering from this issue (note that I'm trying to upload from a macOS machine).  My work around is to simply copy the relevant provision profile into the kpp_upload folder (with the Jenkins home) and then restart Jenkins.